# codeigniter before submit confirm popup box using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I need when I click the button for submit view popup box for confirmation and **if I press ok, it will continue the submit and if cancel nothing will happen and close the box**

here is my code,

**code in the view form**

```
<?php
    foreach($company_data as $row){
?>
    <h2>Company Details.</h2>

    <?php echo form_open_multipart('site/update');?>
    <?php form_hidden('id', $row->code);?>
    <label>Code : </label> <?php echo form_input('code',$row->code);?><br/><br/>
    <label>Name : </label> <?php echo form_input('name',$row->name);?><br/><br/>
    <label>Logo : </label><input type="file" name="userfile"/><br/><br/>
    <label>URL : </label> <?php echo form_input('url',$row->url);?><br/><br/>
    <label>Description : </label> <textarea name="description" rows="4" cols="50"><?php echo $row->description; ?></textarea><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" onclick="update(<?php echo $row->name;?>)"/>
    </form>

    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `confirm()` dialog in your update function like this:

```
function update(args){
   if(confirm('Do you want to submit?')){
      // put all the js code here.
   }else{
      return false;
   }
}
```

So whenever you call your update function it will show a confirm box to ask user to submit the form if user clicks ok then it submits else form won't get submitted.

Comment: if you could add your update function in your question above.

Comment: I have no idea,shall I give the controller and model

Comment: See you have this written on your submit button `onclick="update(<?php echo $row->name;?>)"`, so can you post this function in your question above.

Answer (score 0):

in onclick function call a javascript function and create confirm box using java script and check the return value from the confirm box if it is true then submit the form by using javascript onsubmit function

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer

```
        <form action="<?php echo site_url('site/update'); ?>" name="myForm"  onsubmit="return(validate());">  
    <?php// echo form_open_multipart('site/update');?>
    <?php form_hidden('id', $row->code);?>
    <label>Code : </label> <?php echo form_input('code',$row->code);?><br/><br/>
    <label>Name : </label> <?php echo form_input('name',$row->name);?><br/><br/>
    <label>Logo : </label><input type="file" name="userfile"/><br/><br/>
    <label>URL : </label> <?php echo form_input('url',$row->url);?><br/><br/>
    <label>Description : </label> <textarea name="description" rows="4" cols="50"><?php echo $row->description; ?></textarea><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
    </form>

    <?php } ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
     var r=confirm("Do you want to update this?")
    if (r==true)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, here's the classic jQuery way to do this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( 'form#yourFormId' ).submit( function(){
        if( confirm('Really submit this form?') ){
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    })
})
```

However, your code doesn't appear to submit the form directly, so this probably won't work with your code as written.

You haven't provided the code for the `update()` method specified in your onClick attribute, but you should be able to add confirmation code to the top of it like this:

```
function update(name){
    if( !confirm('Really submit this form?') ){
        return FALSE;
    }

    // ....the rest of your code...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can use below one line**

```
<?php
    foreach($company_data as $row){
?>
    <h2>Company Details.</h2>

    <?php echo form_open_multipart('site/update');?>
    <?php form_hidden('id', $row->code);?>
    <label>Code : </label> <?php echo form_input('code',$row->code);?><br/><br/>
    <label>Name : </label> <?php echo form_input('name',$row->name);?><br/><br/>
    <label>Logo : </label><input type="file" name="userfile"/><br/><br/>
    <label>URL : </label> <?php echo form_input('url',$row->url);?><br/><br/>
    <label>Description : </label> <textarea name="description" rows="4" cols="50"><?php echo $row->description; ?></textarea><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" onclick="return confirm(<?= $row->name ?>);"/>
    </form>

    <?php } ?>
```